# Inequality with conditional expectation of positive random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality, conditional-expectation

Assume $X$ and $Y$ are a.s. positive random variables. Moreover, $X \le Y$ a.s.

It seems to me that this inequality is not always true:
$$
\mathbb{E}[X ~|~ X > a] \mathbb{P}(X > a) \le \mathbb{E}[Y ~|~ Y > a) \mathbb{P}(Y > a)
$$
and I look for the conditions on $X$ and $Y$ under which the above inequality holds.

Comment: Can you give an example of such $X$ and $Y$ for which the inequality doesn't hold?

Comment: @Math1000, wait, i thought i could, but just now I found a mistake. Am I write that both $\mathbb{E} [X ~|~ X > a] \le \mathbb{E}[Y ~|~ Y > a]$ and $\mathbb{P}(X > a) \le \mathbb{P}(Y > a)$ holds, hence implying the result I asked for.

Comment: I believe what you're asking boils down to: Does $\mathbb P(X>a)\leqslant \mathbb P(Y>a)$ for all $a\geqslant0$ imply that $\mathbb E[X\mid X>a]\leqslant \mathbb E[Y\mid Y>a]$ for all $a\geqslant 0$?

Comment: aren't both these statements true independently? If $Y \ge X$ a.s., then $\mathbb{E}[Y ~|~ Y > a] \ge \mathbb{E}[X ~|~ X > a]$ and letting $Y = X + \alpha$ for positive r.v. $\alpha$ we have $\mathbb{P}(X > a) = \mathbb{P}(X + \alpha > a + \alpha) = \mathbb{P}(Y > a + \alpha) \le \mathbb{P}(Y > a)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original inequality holds all the time, but your reasoning in the main comment thread is wrong.

> Claim: $E[X \mid X > a] P(X > a) \le E[Y \mid Y > a] P(Y > a)$

Proof: For any event $A$, let $1_{A}$ denote its ($0,1$-valued) indicator random variable.  Then

- $LHS = E[X \cdot 1_{X>a}]$
- $RHS = E[Y \cdot 1_{Y>a}]$
- $Y \ge X$ a.s. implies whenever $X>a$ then $Y>a$ a.s., therefore $1_{Y>a} \ge 1_{X>a}$ a.s.
- $Y \ge X > 0$ a.s. and $1_{Y>a} \ge 1_{X>a}\ge 0$ a.s. $\implies Y \cdot 1_{Y>a} \ge X \cdot 1_{X>a}$ a.s. $\implies RHS \ge LHS$

> Claim: $E[X \mid X > a] \le E[Y \mid Y > a] $ can be false

Counter-example: $X$ takes value $1$ or $100$ with equal prob $1/2$ each, and let $Y=X+2$ (surely).  Thus, $Y$ takes value $3$ or $102$ with equal prob $1/2$ each.  Conditioned on each variable being $> a = 2$, we have:

- $E[X \mid X > 2] = 100$ since $X=1$ is ruled out
- $E[Y \mid Y > 2] = {3 + 102 \over 2} < 100$